# Is there a way to adjust the padding below the superappbar?

Tags: flutter, dart, navbar

I am using the [SuperCupertinoNavigationBar](https://pub.dev/packages/super_cupertino_navigation_bar) and it is rendering unwanted padding below the appbar that I cannot seem to get rid of.

[image: This padding is what I'm looking for]

[image: This is the padding being rendered by the SuperCupertino stuff]

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fitapp/components/theme/color_lib.dart';
import 'package:super_cupertino_navigation_bar/super_cupertino_navigation_bar.dart';
import 'package:fitapp/components/appbar.dart';
import 'package:fitapp/util/create_exercise_widget.dart';
import 'package:fitapp/database/exerciselist.dart';
import 'package:fitapp/database/exerciselist_db.dart';

class Exercises extends StatefulWidget {
  const Exercises({super.key});

  @override
  State<Exercises> createState() => _ExercisesState();
}

class _ExercisesState extends State<Exercises> {
  Future<List<ExerciseList>>? futureExercises;
  final exerciseDB = ExerciseListDB();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchExercises();
  }

  void fetchExercises() {
    setState(() {
      futureExercises = exerciseDB.fetchAll();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: context.theme.appColors.background,
      body: SuperScaffold(
        appBar: SuperAppBar(
            backgroundColor: context.theme.appColors.background.withOpacity(0.5),
            previousPageTitle: "",
            title: Text("Exercises"),
            searchBar: SuperSearchBar(
              enabled: false,
            ),
            largeTitle: SuperLargeTitle(
              enabled: true,
              largeTitle: "Exercises",
              height: 45,
            )
        ),
        body: SafeArea(
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 25.0, right: 25.0),
                  child: FutureBuilder<List<ExerciseList>>(
                    future: futureExercises,
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                        return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                      } else {
                        final exercises = snapshot.data!;
                        return exercises.isEmpty
                            ? const Center(
                          child: Text(
                            'No Exercises...',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 28,
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                            : ListView.separated(
                          separatorBuilder: (context, index) =>
                              Divider(
                                height: 0,
                                thickness: 0.75,
                                color: context.theme.appColors.onSecondaryContainer,
                              ),
                          itemCount: exercises.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            final exercise = exercises[index];
                            return ListTile(
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                  topLeft: index == 0
                                      ? const Radius.circular(12)
                                      : Radius.zero,
                                  topRight: index == 0
                                      ? const Radius.circular(12)
                                      : Radius.zero,
                                  bottomLeft: index == exercises.length - 1
                                      ? const Radius.circular(12)
                                      : Radius.zero,
                                  bottomRight: index == exercises.length - 1
                                      ? const Radius.circular(12)
                                      : Radius.zero,
                                ),
                              ),
                              tileColor: context.theme
                                  .appColors.primaryContainer,
                              title: Text(
                                exercise.name,
                                style: const TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                              ),
                              trailing: IconButton(
                                onPressed: () async {
                                  await exerciseDB.delete(exercise.id);
                                  fetchExercises();
                                },
                                icon: const Icon(
                                    Icons.delete, color: Colors.red),
                              ),
                              onTap: () {
                                showDialog(
                                  context: context,
                                  builder: (context) =>
                                      CreateExerciseWidget(
                                        exercise: exercise,
                                        onSubmit: (name) async {
                                          await exerciseDB.update(
                                              id: exercise.id, name: name);
                                          fetchExercises();
                                          if (!mounted) return;
                                          Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                        },
                                      ),
                                );
                              },
                            );
                          },
                        );
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  bottom: 16.0,  // Adjust the top value as needed
                  right: 16.0,  // Adjust the right value as needed
                  child: FloatingActionButton(
                    child: const Icon(Icons.add),
                    onPressed: () {
                      showDialog(
                        context: context,
                        builder: (_) => CreateExerciseWidget(
                          onSubmit: (name) async {
                            await exerciseDB.create(name: name);
                            if (!mounted) return;
                            fetchExercises();
                          },
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

I've tried playing around with the padding of the different features of the superappbar, adjusting its height, changing the stuff rendered in the body. I've had no luck. The code rendered in the body has no padding issues with other appbars, just this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no extra space from the `SuperAppBar` itself, the extra space comes from `SafeArea`. You can still use `SafeArea` but disable it only for the `top` part.

```dart
body: SafeArea(
  top: false,
  // ...
)
```

You also need to remove the default padding from the `ListView`:

```dart
ListView.separated(
  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0),
  // ...
)
```

Comment: I've tried that now and it didnt do anything @Dhafin Rayhan

Comment: Make sure you're adding `top: false` to your existing `SafeArea`, not making another new `SafeArea`

Comment: Yes I have done `top: false` to the existing SafeArea and nothing

Comment: Apparently there is an additional padding from the `ListView.separated`, remove it by setting `padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0)` (I've edited the answer)

Comment: YES! That was it, thank you my friend <3